# How to wait for response from server on browser refresh to save those data in localStorage?

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage, settimeout, page-refresh

On browser/page refresh, I need to save some data to localStorage so that data for every page in the angular route will be available through localStorage after the refresh. The below code without setTimeout is working as expected for this.

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  beforeunloadHandler(event) {
    setTimeout(()=>{  
      localStorage.setItem('test','test123');
 }, 3000);
    event.returnValue = false
  }
```

However there are scenario when refresh happens during/before data being fetched from server. For this I need to wait browser refresh till data comes from server.
The above code only set the item in localStorage on cancel click of browser refresh warning of reload.
[image]

How to execute it on reload?
Thanks.